# Magento 2.3.1 not decreasing quantity when order is placed

Tags: magento2.3.1, inventory

I recently upgraded to magento 2.3.1. After update, I noticed that product quantity is not decreased when order is placed (even though **Decrease Stock When Order is Placed** is set to **Yes**) so I decreased quantity via a cronjob. But now when I try to mark an order shipped I get error **Not all of your products are available in the requested quantity**, any suggestions on how to fix that, please?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you see stock figures against your products in the admin?  Maybe you are missing inventory_stock_1 view table?

Check it doesn't exist first then run this SQL to insert.

```
CREATE
OR REPLACE
VIEW `inventory_stock_1` AS select
    distinct `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` AS `product_id`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`website_id` AS `website_id`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`stock_id` AS `stock_id`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`qty` AS `quantity`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable`,
    `product`.`sku` AS `sku`
from
    ( `cataloginventory_stock_status` `legacy_stock_status`
join `catalog_product_entity` `product` on
        (( `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` = `product`.`entity_id` )));
```

Comment: I do have inventory_stock_1 in db and it seems to have correct data